# Tailwind responsive grid not working in angular 8

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am trying to add  [Tailwind css](https://tailwindcss.com/) in a new Angular 8 project but for some reason the responsive grids not working, the other components like cards, button etc are working great.
I am following this article [medium](https://medium.com/p/6e9264e97329/responses/show)

In my global styles.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And I have added in angular.json my customWebpackConfig.
And in HTML if I use

```
<div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/6 mb-4 bg-gray-500"></div>
```

it does not show any element, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem here at all. It is working exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your div has no content. If you want a gray line, you need to use `pb-4` instead of `mb-4`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- If you want a gray line, you should be using pb-4 -->
<div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/6 pb-4 bg-gray-500"></div>

<!-- instead of mb-4, because it has no content to apply the bg-gray-500 to. -->
<div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/6 mb-4 bg-gray-500"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I just copy the code from tailwind documentation without using brain